# Visual Studio Code - Remote Debugging Bazel C++ - Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://dev- file

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio-code, bazel

I'm trying to do remote debugging of bazel project in docker.
Local plugins: Remote Development
Docker plugins (defined in devcontainer.json): ms-vscode.cpptools

My launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/execroot/tf_serving/bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/tensorflow_serving/fplugin/fserve_cc",
      "externalConsole": false,
    }
  ]
}
```

However I'm getting an error:

```
Unable to open 'fserve.cc': Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://dev-container+2f55736572732f6d67756d6f77736b2f776f726b2f6f766d732d63/proc/self/cwd/tensorflow_serving/fplugin/fserve.cc
```

In local development I would add sourceFileMap, however it doesn't seem to work for remote docker development. Any ideas?

Comment: I've found an issue page, but it's currently no response. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2871

Answer (score 0):

when you try to compile with bazel, you will have 4 soft link(bazel-bin, bazel-{source-folder}, bazel-out, bazel-testlog)
modify this attribute wi

"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-",

Comment: Welcome to SO. That feels a bit hackery, it might be a temporary workaround, but doesn't feel like a full solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your problem is due to remote debugging. I believe that the following info will work whether or not you're in a remote environment.

Bazel generates a few symlinks in your project's root folder that contain useful data (for more [see the docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/output_directories.html)):

- `bazel-bin` is a symlink to a folder in the output directory that contains generated code and binaries for the latest configuration of the build you've run.
- `bazel-{folder-name}` is a symlink to the execRoot, which is how bazel sees your project's source code. `{folder-name}` is the name of the folder your project is in.
- `bazel-out` is a symlink to bazel's output root.
- `bazel-testlog` is a symlink to the outputs from test runs

### If you're not using bazel's runfiles library

To provide VSCode with sources at the right location, modify the `"cwd"` attribute in `launch.json` to:

```json
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-{folder-name}",`
```

### If you are using runfiles

You're using runfiles if your program requires files in a `data` attribute in any of its dependencies

First, set `"cwd"` to the root of the runfiles tree for your binary, and then set `"sourceFileMap"` in a way that maps the current working directory to the execRoot symlink. For me (on linux), `/proc/self/cwd` maps correctly, but that might not be true for you. I was able to tell that I got it wrong because VSCode complained about being unable to read a file at `/proc/self/cwd/external/external-project/src/file.cpp`.

```json
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-bin/path/to/executable/executable.runfiles/{workspace-name}`,
"sourceFileMap": {
    "/proc/self/cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-{folder-name}`,
},
```

`{workspace-name}` can be found in `WORKSPACE`, it will look like `workspace(name = "my-project")`. If there is no workspace name defined in that file, it defaults to `__main__`.

I might also recommend changing the `"program"` attribute to a more convenient location. If the last thing you did was build your binary with bazel, you can find the built executable at `bazel-bin/path/to/executable/executable`

A full example:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch Debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            // path to the most recently built version of executable
            // this should be built with `bazel build -c dbg //path/to:executable`
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-bin/path/to/executable/executable",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-bin/path/to/executable/executable.runfiles/{workspace-name}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/proc/self/cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-{folder-name}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Most of this is covered in this useful post (which also shows how to automatically build your executable using `tasks.json`):
https://shanee.io/blog/2019/05/28/bazel-with-visual-studio-code/